# Remove certain recurring elements in xml

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml and want to remove certain elements from the xml document. Initially I wanted to remove the control characters coming in these elements or completely remove the data in these elements.

My sample payload is as below. I wanted to remove resume/content and comments.

```
<Jobs>
 <candidates>
   <address2/>
       <application>
          <comments>&lt;BR />Test emp1&#x0004;711 Newberg St. #4 Oregon, CA 97229   444-123-9752  testcandidate@gmail.com&#x0007;&#x0007;&lt;BR />authorName: Test 1 &#10; &#10;comment content: &lt;b>To: test test (test.test@yahoo.com)&lt;/b>&lt;br />&lt;br />From: abc Recruitment Team (test@abc.com)&lt;br />&lt;br />Subject: Tester at abc&lt;br />&lt;br />&lt;TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">&lt;P ALIGN="LEFT">&lt;FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12" COLOR="#353A3F" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Hello test,&lt;/FONT>&lt;/P>&lt;/TEXTFORMAT>&lt;TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">&lt;P ALIGN="LEFT">&lt;FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12" COLOR="#353A3F" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">&lt;/FONT>&lt;/P>&lt;/TEXTFORMAT>&lt;TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">&lt;P ALIGN="LEFT">&lt;FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12" COLOR="#353A3F" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Thank you for your interest in our abc opening. &lt;/FONT>&lt;/P></comments>
       <disposition>tesr Skills match</disposition>
       <eId>xyz</eId>
        <gender>Male</gender>
      <lastUpdatedDate>1340687163</lastUpdatedDate>
       <race>Undefined</race>
        <resume>
             <content>Test&lt;BR />Human Resources Manager / Business Partner &lt;BR />  portland, Oregon; 4454; &lt;BR /> Phone 020 444456;Mobile 088768999;E-mail test@yahoo.com &lt;BR /></content>
            <format>Text</format>
      </resume>
       <sentDate>1789993473</sentDate>
       <source>Linkedin</source>
       <sourceType>Import</sourceType>
       <veteranStatus>Undefined</veteranStatus>
       <workflowState>Offer Accepted</workflowState>
       <city>portland</city>
       <companyName/>
        <country>US</country>
        <eId>xyz</eId>
    </application>
 </candidates>
 <candidates>
   <address2/>
       <application>
            <comments>&lt;BR />Test emp2&#x0004;711 Newberg St. #4 Oregon, CA 97229 444-123-9752 testcandidate2@gmail.com&#x0007;&#x0007;&lt;BR />authorName: Test 2 &#10; &#10;</comments>
        <disposition>Skills match</disposition>
        <eId>xyz</eId>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <lastUpdatedDate>1340687163</lastUpdatedDate>
        <race>Undefined</race>
            <resume>
                 <content>Test&lt;BR />Program Manager / Business Partner       &lt;BR />  portland, Oregon; 4454; &lt;BR /> Phone 020 444456;Mobile 088768999;E-mail test@yahoo.com &lt;BR /></content>
             <format>Text</format>
        </resume>
         <sentDate>178444473</sentDate>
         <source>Linkedin</source>
         <sourceType>Import</sourceType>
        <veteranStatus>Undefined</veteranStatus>
        <workflowState>Offer Accepted</workflowState>
        <city>portland</city>
        <companyName/>
       <country>US</country>
       <eId>xyzabc</eId>`enter code here`
       </application>
    </candidates>
  </Jobs>
```

Comment: What is your attempt ?

Answer (score 0):

Build the XML into a `Document` using `DocumentBuilderFactory` and pass it to a function like below: (`nodeName` would be "comments" etc.)

```
     removeAllNodes(Document doc, String nodeName){
         DocumentTraversal t = (DocumentTraversal) doc;
         Node root = doc.getDocumentElement();
         NodeIterator iterator = 
              t.createNodeIterator(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);
         for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
             Element e = (Element) n;
             if (nodeName.equals(e.getTagName())) 
                 root.removeChild(e);
         }
     }
```